# How can I get a XML tag value based on the value of another XML tag?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm stuck working with XML and the ElementTree class.  I have the following XML structure:

```
<workItem>
  <stringExtensions>
    <key>key1</key>
    <value>value1</value>
  </stringExtensions>
  <stringExtensions>
    <key>key2</key>
    <value>value2</value>
  </stringExtensions>
  <stringExtensions>
    <key>key3</key>
    <value>value3</value>
  </stringExtensions>
</workItem>
```

What I would like to do is be able to print out the values "value1" and "value3" (not "value2").  To do this I need a way of filtering on the key tag values "key1" and "key3".  My current code:

```
root = ElementTree.fromstring(r.content)
for entry in root.findall("workItem"):
  print(entry.find("stringExtensions").find("value").text)
```

will only print out "value1" since it returns the first result in the XML structure.  I need to add some sort of "where" condition before printing so I can specify, based on the "key" tag value, a specific "value" tag value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Andrew

Comment: explain why and by what rule `key2` should be skipped?

Comment: you can always you standard `if` to check something in Python.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest key2 should be skipped because the value is key2 and not key1 or key3.  I know that sounds ambiguous, but I am only interested in the "value" tag values of key1 and key2.

Comment: @Andrew, so what if there would be `key4` , `key5` and so on ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sorry for late reply.  If there is a key4 and key5 and so on, they should also be ignored.  Regardless of the number of keys, I only want to get the value tag values for key1 and key2 values.

Answer (score 0):

> to get the value tag values for key1 and key3 values

Optimized solution:

```
...
root = ElementTree.fromstring(r.content)
v1 = root.find('./stringExtensions[key="key1"]/value')
v3 = root.find('./stringExtensions[key="key3"]/value')

print(v1.text, v3.text, sep='\n')
```

The output:

```
value1
value3
```